# Can't Boot Live CD In VirtualBox UEFI/EFI Mode

Tags: virtualbox, grub, uefi, f2fs

I really need to boot into a live CD in EFI mode so I can run `update-grub2` but it keeps using BIOS mode for some reason. I set mount points and chroot to the install I want to work on and then update grub and it says `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new: Directory nonexistent`.

I have EFI enabled in the VirtualBox settings. How can I update grub of one of my vdisks? I can't boot that disk until I update grub. I'm operating on an ubuntu install. I've tried 3 different live cds.

Comment: If you have EFI enabled in VirtualBox settings (which you say you do), it's impossible for it to boot in BIOS mode. I don't think that's your problem, just as Rod said on SU.

Comment: Also, you asked this question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1230843/cant-boot-live-cd-in-virtualbox-uefi-efi-mode)\.